# How do I edit a cell in flet's DataTable?

Tags: python, datatable, flet

Flet's [DataTable](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/datatable) has a `show_edit_icon` property, but I don't know how do something when the icon is pressed.

This is an example code:

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.add(
        ft.DataTable(
            columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("First name")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Last name")),
            ],
            rows=[
                ft.DataRow(
                    cells=[
                        ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John"), show_edit_icon=True),
                        ft.DataCell(ft.Text("Smith")),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        ),
    )

ft.app(target=main, view=ft.WEB_BROWSER)
```

I see the edit icon, but how do I connect it to some function that receives the cell that is being edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the doccumentation, In `FLET` data table, [`show_edit_icon`](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/datatable#show_edit_icon) This will only enable you to see the cell's icon. nonetheless, You must create a new function and connect it to the cell on [on_tap](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/datatable#on_tap) functionality.

**Note**:

- Add property `on_tap` to the the cell
- implement a new function
- Update the page after change inside the new function

  ```
  import flet as ft

   def main(page: ft.Page):
       # this is the function that controls the value of the cell 
       # returns value on tap
       def updateOnTap(e):
         e.control.content.value = "Hello John"
         page.update()

       page.add(
           ft.DataTable(
               columns=[
                   ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("First name")),
                   ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Last name")),
               ],
               rows=[
                   ft.DataRow(
                       cells=[
                           ft.DataCell(ft.Text("John"), show_edit_icon=True, on_tap=updateOnTap),
                           ft.DataCell(ft.Text("Smith")),
                       ],
                   ),
               ],
           ),
       )

   ft.app(target=main, view=ft.WEB_BROWSER)
  ```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much! I got to adding on_tap, but I didn't know what to do with the event. I haven't been able to find the documentation for it in Flet's documentation.

Comment: But to type new value on edit button